# AWS Kinesis write throughput has no data, but there are data in total incoming request

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, data-stream

Hi I'm using Kinesis to handle data streaming.

I can successfully send data to Kinesis and pull data from Kinesis, everything is good.

However, when I check the "monitoring" of Kinesis, I see no data for write throughput, but there are data for total incoming request (in attached screenshot). Since i can successfully pull data from Kinesis, I assume there must be some writing throughput, how come no writing throughput in the monitoring?

Or maybe I misunderstand the term "write throughput" and "incoming request"?

Thank you very much.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer from Ryan of Amazon Kinesis:

> Hi keypointt,
>
> This is a known bug in a console. PutRecords throughput is not showing
>   up correctly in the Write Throughput graph. We are actively addressing
>   this issue.
>
> In the meantime, you can navigate to the CloudWatch console and view
>   the correct metric "IncomingBytes".
>
> Apologies to the inconvenience this has caused.
>
> Ryan